# How to access properties of custom list items in Ionic React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a custom list in Ionic similar to this one: https://medium.com/@benchedms/how-to-make-a-to-do-app-with-ionic-react-d92ece061284 but with each item in the list containing an Ionic Range and Input. Right now I can add and delete list items, but I am not sure how to access the values of the ranges and inputs once the list has been created. The list item is defined like this in ListItem.tsx:

```
export const TaskListItem: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ task, onDelete }) => {
  const onClick = () => {
    onDelete(task);
  };
  const [tempo, setTempo] = useState(0);
  return (
    <IonList>
      <IonGrid>
        <IonRow>
          <IonCol>
            Tempo: {tempo}
          </IonCol>
          <IonCol>
            <IonRange min={40} max={200} pin={true} value={tempo} onIonChange={e => setTempo(e.detail.value as number)}/>
          </IonCol>
          <IonCol>
            <IonInput placeholder="Measure number" ></IonInput>
          </IonCol>
          <IonCol>
            <IonIcon className="floatButton paddingRightDelete" name="close" onClick={onClick}/>
          </IonCol>
        </IonRow>
        <IonItemDivider/>
      </IonGrid>
    </IonList>
  );
};
```

And the list is created like this in a file called Home.tsx:

```
<TasksList tasks={this.state.tasks} onDelete={this.deleteTask} />
```

I am trying to access the values of the range within each item in tasks. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, I just had to change setTempo to modify a member variable of the task in ListItem.tsx and then access that variable later.